# Django celery task getting stuck on blocking the chain

Tags: django, locking, task, celery

I am using the celery with python 3.5. I am using chain to perform serialize task and I only want to process single task at a time.
The follow piece of code works fine:

```
@shared_task(name='dummy1')
def dummy1(val):
    logger.info('received: ' + val)

    with RedisLock('testing.pid',60*60):
        try:
            logger.info("Lock acquired by " + val)

            res = chain(dummy2.s(val), dummy3.s(val)).delay()
            logger.info("Lock released")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(str(e))


@shared_task(name='dummy2')
def dummy2(val):
    logger.info('Dummy2 : ' + val)
    time.sleep(3)
    logger.info('Dummy2 complete')
    return None


@shared_task(name='dummy3')
def dummy3(prev, val):
    logger.info('Dummy3 : ' + val)
    time.sleep(3)
    logger.info('Dummy3 complete')
```

RedisLock is a distributed cache based lock for running a single task at a time.
However, when i do:

```
    with RedisLock('testing.pid',60*60):
        try:
            logger.info("Lock acquired by " + val)

            res = chain(dummy2.s(val), dummy3.s(val)).delay()

            res.get()  # blocking the process here
            logger.info("Lock released")
```

the chain does not work as expected and gets crashed very often.

Comment: design your own work-flow? have you seen the celery's built-in ones? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html

Comment: I think chain is one of celery's built-in ones which i am using for my app.

Comment: Good, then use the chain and release the sequential tasks in a queue with one worker, with this config you can run sequential chains as well, no need to lock, I have experience running chains and chords in big deployments and I recommend you let the broker make this for you to avoid the "hidden" costs of maintaining your own.